# Should I check internet connection everytime I call a webservice?

Tags: iphone

I just want to know the best practise to test internet connection availability.
My application uses internet connection for everything.
If I am checking every time that google.com is available or not then definitely I am causing a delay to user to fetch his data every time he is making a request to my server.

So my question is should I check connection availability every time I make a web service request or I should use some kind of global internet checker which should keep the state of internet connection in a particular time period?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rude for your app to use someone else's server (google.com, in this case) to verify internet connectivity.

I would approach this by having a reasonable (probably a few seconds) timeout on the request itself.  Not knowing what API or protocol (HTTP, etc) you're using to make your requests, I can't comment on how to implement such a timeout.

Comment: Setting a request timeout of a few seconds is not a good idea on a mobile device with a potentially slow connection. A better way is to handle the web service requests asynchronously so that they don't lock up the UI. OP might want to look up [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code in my app for checking internet connection.

```
-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet Connection " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hm I know how to check internet I am asking should I always check internet availability before making every request?

Comment: No, you should handle the case where you don't have internet availability or the request times out.